# Magento 2.3 - Add shipping carrier in dropdown to ship order

Tags: magento2.3, carrier

I want to add a new carrier to the dropdown menu inside the shipment tab of a order, to select a custom carrier.

I already tried this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html but that is adding a custom shipping method in the checkout, not to select a carrier inside a order.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: is the change your are trying to do in the backend? can't see any dropdown there..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your carrier model, you need to add the function to enable this shipping method to appear in the backend when your tracking information becomes available.

```
/**
     * Check if carrier has shipping tracking option available
     *
     * All \Magento\Usa carriers have shipping tracking option available
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isTrackingAvailable()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

However, you also want to hide the carrier in the checkout, to do this,

```
/**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

see an example of carrier behaving like you describe at: https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/carrier/src/master/

Comment: Thanks again Herve!

Comment: This comment was the missing link to add tracking links for a custom carrier. First, I followed the [Add custom shipping carrier](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html) tutorial in Magento DevDocs. Second, I installed this [free module available on Github](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.TrackingLink) that enables tracking links in emails. Edit this module's config.xml / system.xml to add the xml tag used in the custom carrier module, and you get custom tracking in emails. `isTrackingAvailable()` method is what enables the dropdown in admin.