# How to create Magento 2 custom carrier tracker?

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.3.4, shipment-tracking, carrier, new-shipment

I want to create custom carrier tracker in magento 2 as like [this](https://nimb.ws/k6DQbS). I want to list my custom carrier tracker in the dropdown.

How can I do this?

Comment: see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310467/magento-2-3-add-shipping-carrier-in-dropdown-to-ship-order

Comment: have you found your answer?

Comment: No, this is for shipping method which you have send

Comment: there is a free module at https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/carrier/src/master/ and if you just install it, you will see that it add a custom carrier for you in the backend

Comment: not opening to download

Comment: should be accessible now

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy, Thank you, but I am asking for something different. I want to add carrier tracker when add tracking number during shipment creation from admin.

Comment: ok, thanks for the update. Apologies, your screenshot was showing something that did strike me as being the same

Answer (score 1):

All you need to add a custom carrier to the "Add tracking number" dropdown is a custom carrier model at *Model/Carrier/YourCustomCarrierName.php*:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;

class YourCustomCarrierName extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'your_custom_carrier_name';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result|bool
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public function isTrackingAvailable(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And a custom *etc/config.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <your_custom_carrier_name>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>Your Custom Carrier Name</title>
                <name>Your Custom Carrier Name</name>
                <model>Company\Module\Model\Carrier\CustomCarrierName</model>
            </your_custom_carrier_name>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the carrier model has been created, just add the following code .

#### File path:

```
YouCompany/ModuleName/Model/Carrier/YourCustomCarrierName.php
```

#### Code

```
   public function isTrackingAvailable(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
```